# Creating mosaic with filenames for each pixel in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, mosaic, pixel

I am producing mosaics from multiple processed landsat scenes. The final product contains maximum values from several rasters. I would like to connect the value in each pixel of the mosaic to the source satellite scene name (which contain the date collected).

Is it possible to add a column with source data to each pixel in the mosaic to new raster in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to be using the [Highest Position](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/highest-position.htm) tool. The output is an integer raster so you could add a new text field storing the name of the raster the value is referencing.

Comment: But if I have 200 input files I would like to be able to store file name immediately to a text field when producing a mosaic, that does not seem possible in highest position?